# Which software framework for developing a HIPAA-compliant web app?

Tags: web-development, programming, framework, r, secure

I am looking for guidance on which software framework(s) to use to build a web application. I'm looking to develop a web application that will:

1. administer an electronic consent,
2. administer questionnaires,
3. save the responses to a secure database,
4. perform automatic scoring of the responses, and
5. right after the respondent completes the questionnaires, present a dashboard of the scored responses to the respondent.

For Step 4, I'd like to either a) use `R` code directly to score the responses, or b) connect to an `R` object on an external droplet via API (e.g., Plumber API). For instance, we could have the web application send the respondents' responses to the Plumber API, have the `R` object on the external droplet perform the `R` processing, and send the score result back to the web application to display on the dashboard to the respondent. The reason I'd like to use `R` for Step 4 is because the current analysis I'm performing is advanced and (to my knowledge) can only currently be conducted in `R`.

I would like the data to be stored securely and for the web application to be HIPAA-compliant. The web application would be deployed either on AWS or on a university server.

The ideal software framework for the web application is one that:

- Has are many (affordable) developers
- Has strong documentation
- And that generates a web application that is:

  - HIPAA-compliant
  - User-friendly, easy to use, fast and responsive, and visually appealing
  - Relatively easy/straightforward to maintain
  - Relatively low cost to develop and deploy
  - Fairly comprehensible by others in the development and scientific community, because I plan to share the source code (without the database credentials etc.)

**Question**: What software framework(s) would you recommend using to build the web application (and why)?

I have considered both `R`/Shiny and Python, but there may be other languages/frameworks that are better suited that I haven't thought of. Shiny is comprehensible by many others in the scientific community because it uses `R` and it would allow native use of `R` code for data processing and scoring, but it has a smaller development community and may have fewer developers familiar with how to make the web application HIPAA-compliant. I'm not particularly familiar with Python or other frameworks, so I'd appreciate any recommendations.